# Parsing multiple images in swift from JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Json has multiple images,

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raEyS.png)

Json has date with multiple images, I want show Date and first image of that Date in tableview, working fine.

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrbtP.png)

Note : 
when click any cell in tableview, display that Date with all images in collection view, But am parsing only first image of that Date,that image only showing in collection view

how to parse all images from Json and pass to collection view from tableview, and display images into collocation view

[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smCZp.png)

this is the code ...

```
json Code    

                    if errorCode == "0" {


                       if let Media_list = jsonData["events"] as? [Any] {

                        self.Mediainfo.removeAll()


                        for i in 0 ..< Media_list.count {

                            if let MediaEventData = Media_list[i] as? [String: Any] {

                                var eventImages = MediaEventData["eventImages"] as? [[String: Any]]

                                if (eventImages?.count)! > 0 {

                                       let bannerImage = eventImages?[0]["bannerImage"] as? String

                                       print(bannerImage as Any)

                                        self.imageUrl = self.url+"/images/events/" + String(describing: bannerImage!)
                                        self.Mediainfo.append(MediaEvent(
                                        eventId: MediaEventData["eventId"]as?String,
                                        date: MediaEventData["date"]as?String,
                                        eventname: MediaEventData["eventName"]as?String,
                                        bannerImages: self.imageUrl


                                    )
                                )

                                  }
                            }






    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Media", for: indexPath)as! MediaCustomTableViewCell

        let  row = indexPath.row

        let media = Mediainfo[row] as MediaEvent

        cell.DisplayDate.text = media.date

        cell.DisplayName.text = media.eventName

        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        cell.DisplayImage.downloadImageFrom(link:media.bannerImages, contentMode: UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit)

        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {

        let media = Mediainfo[(indexPath.row)] as MediaEvent


        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IMAGEVID") as! UITabBarController

        if let viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers,
            let imageController = viewControllers.first as? ImagesCollectionViewController {
            imageController.RecivedData1 = media.bannerImages
        }

        navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBarController, animated: true)




    }
```

collection view Code :

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

        cell.ImageviewCell.downloadImageFrom(link:nameofImages[indexPath.row], contentMode: UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit)


        return cell


    }
```

pls help me......!

Comment: Looks like you did not post all the code.

Comment: for Better under stand of my problem sorry ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>  u can do soemthing like this
> ```
>
> let  eventImages = MediaEventData["eventImages"] as? [[String: Any]]
>
> ```
> if (eventImages?.count)! > 0 {
>
> for i in 0...eventImages.count{
>     let bannerImage = eventImages?[i]["bannerImage"] as? String
>     self.imageUrl = self.url+"/images/events/" + String(describing: bannerImage!)
>
>     self.Mediainfo.append(bannerImage)
>
>   //  or like u did u can append to array
>
>     self.Mediainfo.append(MediaEvent(
>         eventId: MediaEventData["eventId"]as?String,
>         date: MediaEventData["date"]as?String,
>         eventname: MediaEventData["eventName"]as?String,
>         bannerImages: self.imageUrl
>
>     )
>
> } }
> ```

```
In didselect
```

let media = Mediainfo[(indexPath.row)] as MediaEvent
          imageController.RecivedData1 = media.bannerImages

> Your doing like this   Means Your are slecting a particular cell and
>   that index your are passing to NextVC.
>
> if you want to show all images You should pass complete array to
>   nextvc
>
> You should declare a array of same type  Mediainfo array in Next VC
>   and do like
>
> ```
>     EX:  imageController.array = Mediainfo
> ```

Comment: but let bannerImage = eventImages?[0]["bannerImage"] as? String cotain the single images of that. i can append only single images to meidainfo array

Comment: @naga u need to all all images to array right ? run a for loop and add images

Comment: eventImages?.count this is giving count of the images but am not able to append the images to bannerImage if can try showing some where I have modified pls tell me how can get this all images

Comment: imageController.array = Mediainfo this its showing all image in median info my aim is ex 10/08/2017 had 2 images but am display only first image of that day but next collection have to display the 10/08/2017 of 2 images in collection view

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'MediaEvent' at the line of   self.Mediainfo.append(bannerImage)

Comment: @naga thats coz self.Mediainfo i dont know this is of which type array what we can add to this so use below line to this line self.Mediainfo.append(bannerImage)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151562/discussion-between-naga-and-ramesh).